# Read country code from CSV and display the corresponded flag in the Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

As topic. for example.
I have a CSV

> Code,UserID
>
> USA,1234
>
> JPN,1235

I have added flag image USA.png, and JPN.png into the resource.

My program can read the csv raw data and display correctly 
but i have problem in calling the flag by reading the country code in my csv.

I tried this:

```
            Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString.(code)
```

But doesn't work, how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Use GetObject(code) method instead of GetString(code).

var image =  (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(code);
then convert bitmap source to image source.

Comment: @MaulikParmar That is not necessary at all. In WPF you don't deal with bitmap resources as you do in WinForms.